# How to use non static member functions as callback in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino

I am writing a small program for ESP8266 in C++ and run into trouble. 
I've created a Led class form handling leds. The idea is that the class should handle a blink function. For this I use a library called Ticker.

A function in Ticker, attach_ms requires a callback and I cant get that to work with a non static member functions.

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef led_h
#define led_h

#include <Arduino.h> 
#include <Ticker.h>
#include "debugutils.h"

#define tickLength 100


enum class LedState {
        OFF,
        ON,
        SLOW_BLINK,
        FAST_BLINK
};


class Led {
public:

    Led(Ticker *tick, uint8_t ledPin, int slowBlinkTime, int fastBlinkTime);

    void on();
    void off();
    void slowBlink( );
    void fastBlink( );

private:
    uint8_t pin;
    int counter;
    int slowNoBlinkTicks;
    int fastNoBlinkTicks;
    LedState state;
    void ledOn();
    void ledOff();
    void ledInvert();
    void clean();
    void blink(int par);
    void tickerCallbackLed();
};
#endif
```

This is my code file:

```
#include "led.h"


void Led::ledOn() {
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
}

void Led::ledOff() {
     digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}

void Led::ledInvert() {
    digitalWrite(pin, !digitalRead(pin));
}

void Led::clean() {
    counter = 0;
}

void Led::blink(int par) {
    if (counter > par) {
        ledInvert();
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        counter++;
    }
}

void Led::tickerCallbackLed() {

    switch (state) {
        case LedState::OFF : break;
        case LedState::ON : break;
        case LedState::SLOW_BLINK : blink(slowNoBlinkTicks); break;
        case LedState::FAST_BLINK : blink (fastNoBlinkTicks);  break;
        default : break;
    };


};

void Led::on() {
    ledOn();
    state = LedState::ON;
};


void Led::off(){
    ledOff();
    state = LedState::OFF;
};

void Led::slowBlink(){
    clean();
    ledInvert();
    state = LedState::SLOW_BLINK;
};

void Led::fastBlink(){
    clean();
    ledInvert();
    state = LedState::FAST_BLINK;
};


Led::Led(Ticker *tick, uint8_t ledPin, int slowBlinkTime, int fastBlinkTime) {

    tick->attach_ms(tickLength, std::bind(&Led::tickerCallbackLed,this));

    slowNoBlinkTicks = slowBlinkTime/tickLength;
    fastNoBlinkTicks = fastBlinkTime/tickLength;

    pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);

    pin = ledPin;
    state = LedState::OFF;
    counter = 0;

}
```

This line gives a compile error and I dont know how to fix it. Have tried to follow all "advice" I have found on internet.

```
 tick->attach_ms(tickLength, std::bind(&Led::tickerCallbackLed,this));
```

Comment: What compiler error are you getting exactly? Please provide the actual error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this version of `Ticker.h`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Ticker/src/Ticker.h), `Ticker::attach_ms()` is overloaded to accept either a `std::function<void(void)>` or a `void (*)(TArg)` as the callback:

```
typedef void (*callback_with_arg_t)(void*);
typedef std::function<void(void)> callback_function_t;

void attach_ms(uint32_t milliseconds, callback_function_t callback)
{
        _callback_function = callback;
        attach_ms(milliseconds, _static_callback, (void*)this);
}

template<typename TArg>
void attach_ms(uint32_t milliseconds, void (*callback)(TArg), TArg arg)
{
        static_assert(sizeof(TArg) <= sizeof(uint32_t), "attach_ms() callback argument size must be <= 4 bytes");
        uint32_t arg32 = (uint32_t)arg;
        _attach_ms(milliseconds, true, reinterpret_cast<callback_with_arg_t>(callback), arg32);
}
```

In the first case, you can use a lambda with `std::function`, you don't need `std::bind()` at all:

```
tick->attach_ms(tickLength, [this](){ this->tickerCallbackLed(); });
```

In the second case, the `callback` takes a user-defined argument that is passed to `Ticker::attach_ms()`, so you can pass `this` as that argument (which, as you can see above, is exactly what the `std::function` version of `Ticker::attach_ms()` does internally):

```
class Led {
...
private:
    ...
    static void staticTickerCallbackLed(Led *pThis);
    void tickerCallbackLed();
    ...
};

void Led::staticTickerCallbackLed(Led *pThis)
{
    pThis->TickerCallbackLed();
}

...

tick->attach_ms(tickLength, &Led::staticTickerCallbackLed, this);
```

Do note, though, that `Ticker::attach_ms()` does not allow a callback argument that is > 4 bytes in size, which means either approach will not work when compiling for 64-bit, where pointers are 8 bytes!  IMHO, that seems like a bug in the implementation of the internal `Ticker::_attach_ms()` method, which takes in a callback argument as `uint32_t` instead of as `uintptr_t`:

```
void _attach_ms(uint32_t milliseconds, bool repeat, callback_with_arg_t callback, uint32_t arg);
```

Comment: Case 1) Not working for me,, 
"error: no matching function for call to 'Ticker::attach_ms(int, Led::Led(Ticker*, uint8_t, int, int)::__lambda0)'"
Case 2) ok;

Whats problem with first case ??

Comment: @lg.lindstrom well, let's start with the most obvious. Does your version of `Ticker.h` even have the `std::function` overload of `attach_ms()` to begin with? What is the actual compiler error you get when you tried to use `std::bind()`?

Comment: "error: no matching function for call to 'Ticker::attach_ms(int, Led::Led(Ticker*, uint8_t, int, int)::__lambda0)'"

Comment: @lg.lindstrom Does your version of `Ticker.h` even have the `std::function` overload of `attach_ms()` to begin with? Yes or no?